# What is a magnetic line of force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Do magnetic limes of force 'flow'? If so, what is it that is flowing?

What is the 'line of force' composed of?

Comment: What do you mean by "flow", and what is a "line of force"?

Answer (score 2):

No, magnetic lines of force don't flow.  They have a direction, which shows the direction of the magnetic field but there is nothing flowing.  If you were to place a small magnetic dipole at the location of the magnetic field line its north pole would feel a force in the direction of the line of force.

The phrase "line of force" was introduced by Michael Faraday in the 1830s who apparently was [convinced of their physical reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_force).

We now usually refer to "magnetic field lines" which are a visualization tool to help picture a magnetic field's direction and strength in an area.  The field exists - the field lines are just constructions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to @M.Enns that the magnetic lines of force is a brilliant discovery of the great mind like Faraday. They are just the visualization tool. You can visualize the direction and strength of the magnetic field from the direction and density (which is also virtual) of magnetic lines. Sometimes $1\times10^8$ field lines are associated with 1 Weber magnetic flux passing through an area